# Selenium find text of span

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

```
<td style="border-bottom: transparent;padding-bottom:0px;" colspan="14">
 <ul class="pager">
  <span> Total number of rows: 3926 (page 1 of 79)</span>
</ul>
</td>
```

I found the element from pager class,

```
  List<WebElement> webElement = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='pager']"));
          List<WebElement> childElements = webElement.get(0).findElements(By.xpath("./child::*"));
          sout("childElement text " + childElements.get(0).getAttribute("innerHTML")); // returns empty String
          sout("childElement text " + childElements.get(0).getTagName()); // returns "span"
```

also tried this, in chrome it marks with yellow color what I need, but selenium driver cant find it

```
 //*[contains(text(),' Total number of rows')]
```

Comment: Rows number could be set after some calculations. So `span` could be empty initially. Try to use Wait

Answer (score 1):

`span` tag is the child node of `ul` tag. So you can try it as follows:

```
//ul[@class='pager']/span
```

See the result from [here](http://xpather.com/b78HJleK)